# Creating conditional fields based upon previous month values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently doing some work on a dataset that contains monthly data about the subscription status of users, where a given row shows whether a user is subscribed on a given month(shown as truncated date) in the following format:

```
+------------+------+---------------------+
|   month    | user | subscription_status |
+------------+------+---------------------+
| 2022-02-01 | 2345 | true                |
| 2022-01-01 | 2345 | false               |
| 2021-12-01 | 2345 | false               |
| 2022-02-01 | 4578 | true                |
| 2022-02-01 | 9548 | false               |
| 2022-02-01 | 1212 | true                |
|......                                   |
+------------+------+---------------------+
```

What I would like to do is query this data, but also generate a number of extra boolean fields whose values are conditional on the previous monthly subscription data for a given user, e.g:

- `never_subscribed_ever`(subscription_status is false for each month for a user)
- `never_subscribed_last_6_months` (subscription_status is false for the last 6 months only)
- `first_subscribed` (subscription_status is true for the first time)
- `resubscribed` (subscription_status is true after being false last month)

to give a table such as :

```
+------------+------+---------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
|   month    | user | subscription_status | never_subscribed_ever | never_subscribed_last_6_months | first_subscribed | resubscribed |
+------------+------+---------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

However I'm afraid that I am quite lost on how best to implement the logic which I plan to do using the `lag` function along with conditionals such as `if`/`case` when needed.

Can anyone help me get started on the best way to implement lag logic on a user level looking at various past timeframes per field?

Comment: What does your source data look like? Please provide some sample data as it exists in your database (including what datatypes the columns are) and the result you would expect from that sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is a nice little homework of the usage of *analytic functions*.

Most of them are straightforward, only for the `never_subscribed_last_6_months`  you need to apply a windowing clause to get the last 6 months.

**Query**

```
select 
month,
user_id,
subscription_status,
case when 
count(case when  SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS = 'true' then 1 end) 
   over (partition by user_id order by month) = 0 then 'Y' end as never_subscribed_ever,
case when
count(case when  SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS = 'true' then 1 end) 
   over (partition by user_id order by month 
   range between INTERVAL '6' MONTH preceding and current row) = 0 then 'Y' end as  never_subscribed_last_6_months,
min(case when  SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS = 'true' then month end) over (partition by user_id) as first_subscribed,
case when  SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS = 'true' and
 lag(SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS) over (partition by user_id order by MONTH) = 'false' then 'Y' end as resubscribed
from user_status
order by user_id, month desc;
```

*Sample Data*

```
create table user_status as 
select date'2022-02-01' month, 2345 user_id, 'true' subscription_status from dual union all
select date'2022-01-01' month, 2345 user_id, 'false' subscription_status from dual union all
select date'2021-12-01' month, 2345 user_id, 'false' subscription_status from dual union all
select date'2022-02-01' month, 4578 user_id, 'true' subscription_status from dual union all
select date'2022-02-01' month, 9548 user_id, 'false' subscription_status from dual union all
select date'2022-02-01' month, 1212 user_id, 'true' subscription_status from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, hardly use analytic or window functions but your code is nice and clear